# How can I choose which Python interpreter is being used when embedding it in a C program?

Tags: python, c

For a project of mine, I need to embed the Python interpreter in a wider C application, using the interpreter of an Anaconda environment. How can I do so ? I've looked online, but nothing mentions it. I'm guessing I should change something near Py_Initialize(), but what ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifndef PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#endif

#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize(); // Here ?
                     // Maybe something like Py_InitializeInterpreter("whatever/path") ?

    PyObject* pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("script"); 
    PyObject* pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DecRef(pName);

    bool running = false;
    while(running)
    {
        //whatever I need to do
    }

    Py_DecRef(pModule);
    Py_Finalize();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT : I'd just like to point out one thing : I'm not a Python dev by any means, I just need to call Python functions from my C application. The Python itself is coded by someone else, so I don't have much knowledge at all about how it works.

Comment: What do you mean by "choosing Python interpreter"? If you want a specific "environment" then you need to build and link your program in that "environment" with the Python library of that "environment". And more importantly *run* your program in that "environment".

Comment: That's not how it works. An embedded Python interpreter is actually part of your C executable. That's why it's called "embedded". Your Anaconda Python interpreter is a separate executable.

Comment: Depending on what you need to do with Python, it might make more sense to just launch a separate Python process and communicate with it over standard interprocess communication channels, like pipes.